# Usage of yepnope (relative paths, css and js)

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox-2, modernizr, yepnope

I want to include fancybox only when there is no touch device involved. This is my code so far:

```
<script>
    yepnope([{
        test : Modernizr.touch,
        nope  : './js/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js',
        callback : {
            "jquery.fancybox.pack.js": function () {
                console.log("fancybox loaded!");
            }
        }
    }]);
</script>
```

This code is placed before the closing body tag. I get the error `TypeError: k.apply is not a function` but this doesn't help me.

My questions:

- Can I load the js file with this relative path?
- Where does my relative path starts? From the path where yepnope lies?
- How can I conditionally load a JS and a CSS file?

**Update:**

Now I tried a different way:

```
<script>
Modernizr.load([
    {
        test  : Modernizr.mq('screen and (max-width: 31.25em)'),
        yep  : {
            'photoswipe' : ['/js/klass.min.js', '/js/code.photoswipe-3.0.5.min.js']
        },
        nope : {
            'fancybox' : ['/js/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', '/js/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css']
        },
        callback : {
            'photoswipe': function (url, result, key) {
                var myPhotoSwipe = $("a.fancy").photoSwipe({ enableMouseWheel: false , enableKeyboard: false });
            },
            'fancybox': function (url, result, key) {
                $('a.fancy').fancybox();
            }
        }
    }
]);
</script>
```

I get the following error `TypeError: a.split is not a function`. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative paths with `./folder` are possible (with `/` at the beginning not). You also cannot use a key with an array. Either array or separate keys as shown here:

```
<script>
    Modernizr.load({
        test: Modernizr.mq('screen and (max-width: 31.25em)'),
        yep: {
            'photoswipe-klass' : './js/klass.min.js',
            'photoswipe-js' : './js/code.photoswipe-3.0.5.min.js'
        },
        nope: {
            'fancybox-js' : './js/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js',
            'fancybox-css' : './js/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css'
        },
        callback: {
            'photoswipe-js': function (url, result, key) {
                var myPhotoSwipe = $("a.fancy").photoSwipe({ enableMouseWheel: false , enableKeyboard: false });
            },
            'fancybox-js' : function (url, result, key) {
                $('a.fancy').fancybox();
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Q: Can I load the js file with this relative path?*

Yes, provided you have a structure similar to :

```
 index.html
--js/
----lib/
------modernizr.custom.js
--------fancybox/
----------jquery.fancyboxy.pack.js
```

See next answer to explain this...

*Q: Where does my relative path starts? From the path where yepnope lies?*

Modernizr takes the path from the position of the html page, not from the position of the modernizr load script (since it creates that script reference with that path in the html).

*Q: How can I conditionally load a JS and a CSS file?*

Pass in an array to nope instead of the single string for just the JavaScript :

`nope : ['./js/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', './styles/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.css']`

Take a look at the docs, they're pretty good on this...
http://modernizr.com/docs/#load

Comment: `modernizr.custom.js` is on the same level as my `lib` folder (where the `fancybox` folder is in). So my paths should be OK. I don't neeed to include `yepnope.js` separately because I already included it with `modernizr`? So `yepnope` and `Modernizr.load` are the same? I've updated my question. I still don't get it running. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes Modernizr.load calls yepnope so essentially is the same thing `Modernizr.load=function(){yepnope.apply(window,[].slice.call(arguments,0));};` if you want to check this stuff out I'd strongly recommend downloading the dev version of the library so you can see the source.  What errors are coming through on DevTools (or whichever browser debug you use)?   Please also note that the location of modernizr.custom.js is irrelevant to location of other included scripts, because as mentioned path should be specified as from the html page.

Comment: In my last example I get `TypeError: a.split is not a function` from `modernizr.custom.js`. Does the structure from my code looks good? As I understand the key and the callback should be executed when the script has been loaded.

Comment: Ok, cool, thats because the browser you're testing with doesn't support ES5 version of JavaScript and String.split function only exists in browsers that support that version.  You can include a polyfill script to create that function (and the others that are in EcmaScript5), a good one is `https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js`

Comment: Hmm, I'm using FF24 and that doesn't support ES5? http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/ says that it should. Now I included the development version of `modernizr`. Now I get the error `TypeError: Modernizr.load is not a function` at the position `'fancybox'   : function (url, result, key) {`. Seems that modernizr isn't loaded?

Comment: You're right FF24 should support it and on checking its actually in in JavaScript 1.1 ES3, so it must have been something else.  `es5-shim.js` does include a polyfill for String.split though, but it sounds like there is something else happening.  I've tested this on FF in a fairly empty HTML page with other scripts and it works so is it something in fancybox?

Comment: In the `callback` I use `alert(result);` with no instantiation of `fancybox`. Perhaps the loading of `fancybox` produces this problem? I'll try to load something else ...

Comment: If I remove the css from the array (fancybox) than no such error occurs (`nope: { 'fancybox' : '/js/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js'},`). The `result` is false. It loads very slowly because my `alert` is popping up after 30 seconds or so. Than I get `TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function`. What does that mean?